# EF5 Fluent API mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship

I am trying to map these entities:

```
 [Table("AAN_DigitalLib_Asset")]
    public class Asset
    {
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("format_id")]
    public int FormatID { get; set; }

    [Column("person_id")]
    public int? PersonID { get; set; }

    [Column("publicationYear")]
    public int? PublicationYear { get; set; }

    public Person People { get; set; }

    //public virtual AssetKeyword AssetKeywords { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssetKeyword> AssetKeywords { get; set; }
}
```

With these entities:

```
[Table("AAN_DigitalLib_AssetKeyword")]
    public class AssetKeyword
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column("asset_id")]
        public int AssetID { get; set; }

        [Column("keyword")]
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
    }
```

Where a single `Asset` can have many `AssetKeywords`.  There is no relationship specified in the database, so how can I create one using the Fluent API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does adding

```
[ForeignKey("AssetID")]
public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
```

on your AssetKeyword class fix it?

If that doesn't do it, then do this in your onModelCreating()

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetKeyword>()
                    .HasRequired(p => p.Asset)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.AssetID);
```